# PHP push array of object to elasticsearch at once

Tags: php, elasticsearch, guzzle

I have a little problem with my array push. What I'm trying to do, is push array of object to elasticsearch. I have heard about bulk option "$this->elastic->bulk($arrayOfObject);" it doesn't work in my case, cuz my array is automatically numbered. this how the error looks like:

```
        [Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\UnexpectedValueException]                                               
          "0" ... "724" are not valid parameters. Allowed parameters are "_source", "_source_exclude", "_so  
          urce_include", "client", "consistency", "custom", "fields", "filter_path", "human", "pipeline", "pipeli  
          ne", "refresh", "replication", "type"
```

And this is how my object looks like:

```
[724] => Array
    (
        [index] => pans
        [type] => 53
        [id] => 1514
        [body] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15221
                [name] => 1
                [location] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2099856.62422
                        [1] => 6524156.34668
                    )

                [angle] => 234.244154361
                [bugs] => 114
                [serial_no] => 104/5411
                [delayed] => 2
            )

    ))
```

Any ideas what should i do? :)

ps. I don't want to use for loop.